# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'restrict_xpath'

Tags: python, scrapy

Im newbie to scrapy and having the issue below while trying to run my spider.İ read a lot about rules class and still cant figure out the error. what am i missing, is it because the syntax of callback argument

Here is the code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class ParserSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'parser'
    allowed_domains = ['eksisozluk.com/']
    start_urls = ['https://eksisozluk.com//']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpath='//div[@id="mobile-index"]/ul/li'),callback='parse_item', follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpath='//div[@id="topic"]/div[1]/div[2]/a[2]'))
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'title': response.xpath("//h1[@id='title']/text()").get(),
            'entry': response.xpath("//div[@class='content']text()").get(),
            'yazar': response.xpath("//a[@class='entry-author']/text()").get(),
            'title': response.xpath("//a[@class='entry-date permalink']/text()").get(),

        }
```

and output:

```
 File "/home/bodhi/Desktop/scrape_projects/eksi_parser/eksi_parser/spiders/parser.py", line 6, in <module>
    class ParserSpider(CrawlSpider):
  File "/home/bodhi/Desktop/scrape_projects/eksi_parser/eksi_parser/spiders/parser.py", line 12, in ParserSpider
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpath='//div[@id="mobile-index"]/ul/li'),callback='parse_item', follow=True),
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'restrict_xpath'
```

Comment: Is `restrict_xpath` an actual argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct argument is `restrict_xpaths` with `s` instead `restrict_xpath`.

Comment: wow thx a lot mate.. i was about to lose my mind omg.. i feel so lame

Comment: No problem, you are welcome. Please select mark the question as answered if the problem is solved.